# Infowindo is empty

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow, google-fusion-tables

Info Window in the map is showing empty.But it has data in it.After i drag with my mouse pointer data is dhown.Initially at time of loading info window content is white in color.please can anyone help me.

https://plus.google.com/photos/105174565434954710248/albums/5716765698153660673?authkey=CLyst5Pn2OLMTQ

Comment: Can you provide a link to the table or the website containing the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some css/style you're setting text as white. Check style with internet explorer's F12 or FF Firebug...